# Unique factorization domain: existence of a complex number

Tags: number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $w = (-1 + i \sqrt{3})/2$ and $\mathbb Z[w] = \{ m + nw \mid m, n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Why is there for every $z \in \mathbb C$ a $q \in \mathbb Z[w]$ such that $|z-q| < 1$?

Comment: Draw disks of unit radius around some lattice points defined by this domain and observe how they overlap.  You get the same thing with $\sqrt{-3}$ replaced with $\sqrt{-7}$ and with $\sqrt{-11}$ too.

Comment: Three closest neighbours of the lattice are located at the vertices of the equilateral triangle with side one, so $|z-q|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $\mathbf Z[ω]$ (seen in the Argand-Cauchy plane) is a lattice in $\mathbf R^2$, and its fundamental region is a rhombus with sides equal to $1$. So any point in the rhombus is inside  one of the unit circles centred at one of the vertices of the rhombus.

Comment: Is the name *Argand-Cauchy plane* commonly used for the complex plane? I've never seen it before but it sounds pretty nice :)

Comment: In France, we say usually ‘plan d'Argand’ to emphasize the geometric aspects of complex numbers. In English, it is also used, but the most common denomination  is ‘complex plane’ – which is ambiguous in my opinion, as it might as well denote $\mathbf C^2$. Related to this are the notions of image of a complex number, and the affix of a point in the plane.

Comment: The more you know... In Germany it was introduced to me as "Gaußsche Zahlenebene", i.e. Gaussian number plane.

Comment: As usual, new (at the time) notions may have several fathers (and even mothers)…

Comment: And why exactly does follow that $\mathbb Z[w]$ is a unique factorization domain? (I read this somewhere...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!